# Conditionally terminate current line before System.out.println

Tags: java, println, system.out

**EDIT:** Note that the code below is an *example* to show what I want to do. My real question is, in Raphael Schweikert's words, **how (if at all possible) you can inspect previously printed output?** In other words, what test can be placed at the placeholder `/*SOME TEST HERE*/` to determine if the cursor of `System.out` is currently at the beginning of a new line or not.

This might be a strange question. Bear with me. Assume the following Java code:

```
public void method1() {
    method2();
    System.out.println("line1");
    method2();
    System.out.print("line2");
    method2();
}

public void method2() {
    System.out.println("method2");
}

OUTPUT when method1 called:
method2
line1
method2
line2method2
```

Notice that the last line where the line2 and method2 printouts appear in one line. I would like to avoid that, but I also don't want an extra empty line to appear after line1 printout. So I wish to rewrite method2 as follows:

```
public void method2() {
    if (/* SOME TEST HERE */) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("method2");
}

OUTPUT when method1 called:
method2
line1
method2
line2
method2
```

Is there any test that can be done here to make this happen?

*Note: Please see edit section at top.*

Comment: Is the question about how you can add the missing newline for this particular case or is this a general question about how (if at all possible) you can inspect previously printed output?

Comment: Second one. That's where **all** the answers are going wrong.

Comment: Thought so! Unfortunately, I’m pretty sure this is impossible. As far as your application is concerned, sent output is – well – sent. The fact that it is retained by a console is irrelevant (one could fathom some native API querying the containing console but this would have to be specific to the implementation of said console – if at all possible). Your best bet is to use your own function (or own `PrintStream` implementation) which would use `System.out` but keep track of the last character sent.

Comment: Thank you for the well-informed comment. It is quite sad that creators of Java overlooked this. They could have added `System.out.lnprint()` and `System.out.lnprintln()` methods _(for example)_ to automatically remember if it's a new line and conditionally start another if it's not. Without such functions, console programmers have to keep track of new lines when writing their code when this could have been better handled by the system behind the scenes. But I guess there isn't any other way than to use my own function/implementation.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert If you place your comments as an answer (and reformat it nicely with a little more expansion) I'll accept it as "accepted answer". Save yours, nothing here among the responses is good. (It almost seems people cannot distinguish between code samples and real-world applications.)

Comment: It would make more sense to me if Java `print` and `println` worked in such a way that `println` always starts a new line before printing. That way I can start off with a `println` then add more content to the same line using `print`. Then when I have something to print on a new line, I'd just call `println` again. I don't **EVER** have to worry about what I printed last. It's more logical and sensible than the ridiculous setup that Java creators thought of - to have `println` print to the current line _then_ start a new line. But oh well, all I can do is rant _(or do custom implementations)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I’m pretty sure this is impossible. As far as your application is concerned, sent output is just that: sent. If you don’t want to write some (possibly JNI-only) code to interface with the enclosing console, your best hope is to use your own implementation that keeps track of newlines being sent.

I’ve tried doing this with a PrintStream that wraps System.out (or System.err). This is by no means complete and also lacks the synchronized access protections of the originals. Also, it is dependent on some implementation details of the superclass which is a bad thing™.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class LineEndingAwarePrintStream extends PrintStream {
    private boolean didEndLine;

    public LineEndingAwarePrintStream(PrintStream inner) {
        super(inner);
        didEndLine = false;
    }   

    @Override
    public void print(char arg0) {
        didEndLine = arg0 == '\n';
        super.print(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void print(char[] arg0) {
        if(arg0.length > 0) {
            didEndLine = arg0[arg0.length-1] == '\n';
        }
        super.print(arg0);
    }
    @Override
    public void print(String arg0) {
        if(arg0.length() > 0) {
            didEndLine = arg0.charAt(arg0.length()-1) == '\n';
        }
        super.print(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void println() {
        super.println();
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(boolean arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(char arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(char[] arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(double arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(float arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(int arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(long arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(Object arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void println(String arg0) {
        super.println(arg0);
        didEndLine = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(boolean b) {
        super.print(b);
        didEndLine = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void print(double d) {
        super.print(d);
        didEndLine = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void print(float f) {
        super.print(f);
        didEndLine = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void print(int i) {
        super.print(i);
        didEndLine = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void print(long l) {
        super.print(l);
        didEndLine = false;
    }
    @Override
    public void print(Object obj) {
        super.print(obj);
        didEndLine = false;
    }
    public void assertNewLine() {
        if(!didEndLine) {
            this.println();
        }
    }

    public void printOnNewLine(Object arg) {
        this.assertNewLine();
        this.println(arg);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        LineEndingAwarePrintStream out = new LineEndingAwarePrintStream(System.out);
        out.println("New line");
        out.printOnNewLine("Not two newlines");
        out.print("New line");
        out.println("No new line");
        out.print("New line");
        out.printOnNewLine("New line");
        out.append('3');
        out.printOnNewLine("New line");
        out.append("Test");
        out.append('\n');
        out.printOnNewLine("Not two newlines");
        out.append("Test\n");
        out.printOnNewLine("Not two newlines");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work =) You may however wish to use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n` to make it platform-independent.

Comment: Line separators that don’t end in (or equal) `'\n'` are relatively uncommon nowadays. Detecting `'\n'` is fine on unix, mac and windows (because the windows line-separator ends in `'\n'` as well) and the overhead necessary to detect `'\r'`, `"\n\r"`, or the record separator (whose escape sequence I can’t seem to find anywhere) isn’t worth the added complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, sorry the question title differs from it's content...

If you wish to know last character sent to `System.out` you should write your own `PrintStream` derived class

```
class PrintStreamEx extends PrintStream {

   // replacing out code
   static PrintStream oldout = System.out;
   static PrintStreamEx newout = new PrintStreamEx();

   static {
        System.setOut(newout);
   }

   private char lastchar;

   // wrap old out
   public PrintStreamEx() {
       super(oldout);
   }

   // intercept all writing methods 
   // for example

   @Overrides
   public void print(String s) {
       lastchar = s.charAt(s.lenght()-1);
       super.print(s);
   }

   // provide a method to get last char
   public char lastChar() {
        return lastchar;
   }


}
```

and wrap `System.out` into it. Inside your class you will be able to keep last character sent as shown above.

To set your class to work, you should use `System.setOut()` method.

(I modified example to implement this too)

Comment: Good suggestion but I think it's incomplete. I don't want to get the last character, but I rather want the stream to remember the last character and decide internally whether to start a new line or not.

Comment: And I don't understand how the title is so different from the content. The content should be considered an elaboration of the title (which is summary), something many users overlook in a race to be the first to answer. The title clearly states that I want to _conditionally_ terminate current line. The content goes on to elaborate what that means by giving an example. It _even_ had very specific instructions on how I expect `method2()` to be modified, with a template of the modified `method2()`. Yet disappointingly, I got some 5 answers all suggesting modifications that weren't even asked for.

Comment: @ADTC, generally, you should not encapsulate such decisions into the stream. Let caller decide this.

Comment: But that is what I want in the stream (at least in a custom implementation, since I'm implementing it).

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 System.out.print("line2")
```

to

```
 System.out.println("line2")
```

println print the thing with new line

corrected one

```
public void method1() {
method2();
System.out.println("line1");
method2();
System.out.println("line2");
method2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
method2();
System.out.println("line1");
method2();
System.out.println("line2");
method2();
```

`System.out.print()` will print the output in the same line

**OUTPUT**

```
method2
line1
method2
line2
method2
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what I'm looking for. Please read question again. I would like method2() to automatically determine whether to print in same line or new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator

`System.out.print("method2" + (newline?"\n":""));`

or

`System.out.print((newline?"\n":"") + "method2");`

Comment: I'm guessing `newline` is a boolean variable? In any case, sorry but your answer is also not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int k=0;
if(k<1)
{
System.out.print("method2.");
k=k+1;
}
else
{
System.out.println("method2");
}
```

Comment: Good try but ignoring the dependence on a static variable, what's the logic here? Btw, please read my edit to the question.